# problem returned type of fields with expl3 and siunitx

Tags: siunitx, expl3, xparse

I made a list of key-value, that I can get and set, but when i'm trying to display the stored number in engineering writing, it gives me an error : Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input '\GetField {varB}'.

I'm not so much familiar with expl3, I think I understand that it comes from the "n" that should be "c" for how the argument is returned but I tried different configurations without success.

If someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong and what I should change

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[binary-units=true, detect-all]{siunitx}[=v2]


\sisetup {
    exponent-to-prefix  = true,         % convert exponents into belonging prefixes
    round-mode          = places,
    per-mode            = symbol,
    per-symbol          = /
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_FieldList_prop

\cs_new:Nn \td_store_property:nn {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_FieldList_prop {#1} {#2}
}

%Defining key-value interface
 \keys_define:nn {FieldList} {
    varA               .code:n = {\td_store_property:nn {varA}{#1} },
    varB     .code:n = {\td_store_property:nn {varB}{#1} },
    varC              .code:n = {\td_store_property:nn {varC}{#1} },
    varD              .code:n = {\td_store_property:nn {varD}{#1} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\FieldList}{+m}{
  \prop_gclear:N \g_FieldList_prop% Clearing the property list
  % Set the keys
  \keys_set:nn {FieldList}{#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetField}{m}{
    \prop_item:Nn \g_FieldList_prop {#1}% Extract the key #1 from the property list

}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\FieldList{
    varA             = 500,
    varB            = {1e11},
    varC            = {8.54e11},
    varD            = Si
}

\noindent 1: \GetField{varB} -          \num{\GetField{varB}}\\


\end{document}
```

Thanks !
Cheers

Comment: Use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetField}` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand{\GetField}`.

Comment: wow, it was much simpler than what I thought.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're improperly using protection. For instance, your `\cs_new:Nn` should be `\cs_new_protected:Nn`, because it does an assignment. However, the function can be dispensed with, for you can use `.prop_gput:N` that does exactly the same.

Commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are protected; for expandable ones, that you want in the argument to `\num`, use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` (you can, because `\prop_item:Nn` is fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  binary-units       = true,
  exponent-to-prefix = true,
  round-mode         = places,
  per-mode           = symbol,
  per-symbol         = /,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_drstu_FieldList_prop

%Defining key-value interface
\keys_define:nn {drstu/FieldList}
  {
    varA .prop_gput:N = \g_drstu_FieldList_prop,
    varB .prop_gput:N = \g_drstu_FieldList_prop,
    varC .prop_gput:N = \g_drstu_FieldList_prop,
    varD .prop_gput:N = \g_drstu_FieldList_prop,
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\FieldList}{m}
 {
   % Clearing the property list
   \prop_gclear:N \g_drstu_FieldList_prop
   % Set the keys
   \keys_set:nn {drstu/FieldList} {#1}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetField}{m}
 {
   % Extract the key #1 from the property list
   \prop_item:Nn \g_drstu_FieldList_prop {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\FieldList{
    varA = 500,
    varB = {1e11},
    varC = {8.54e11},
    varD = Si
}

\noindent 1: \GetField{varB} --- \num{\GetField{varB}}

\end{document}
```

[image]